# The zoo car park

Tags: algebra-precalculus

In the zoo car park there were 780 vehicles. Most of the vehicles were cars,but one section contained coaches only.the ratio of cars to coaches was 11:2. How many vehilces were cars and how many were coaches?

Answer (score 2):

Let $x$ be the number of cars, and $y$ the number of coaches.

Then we have that $$x + y = 780\tag{1}$$ $$\dfrac xy = \dfrac{11}{2} \implies 2x = 11y\tag{2}$$

with the second equation assuming $y \neq 0$.

From $(1)$, we have $y = 780-x$. Substituting $y$ into equation $(2)$ gives us $$2x = 11(78 - x) \iff 13x = 858 \iff x = 660$$ Now solve for $y$ using equation $(1)$.

Answer (score 0):

The ratio $11:2$ is saying, "for every $11+2=13$ vehicles, $11$ are coaches and $2$ are cars". The first step is to set up a proportion. Let's find out how many vehicles are coaches first.
$$\frac{\text{number of coaches}}{\text{total vehicles}}=\frac{x}{780}=\frac{11}{13}$$
$$13x=11\times 780$$
$$x=\frac{11\times 780}{13}=660$$
There were $660$ coaches. Knowing this, we can find out how many cars there are.
$$\text{Total vehicles}=\text{Number of coaches}+\text{Number of cars}$$
$$780=660+\text{Number of cars}$$
$$\text{Number of cars}=780-660=120$$
There were $120$ cars and $660$ coaches in the zoo car park.

Hope I helped!